# Getting an error from the Stanford iOS Class, but my code seems identical

Tags: ios, objective-c

I believe I did what the instructor did verbatim, but my app (it's a simple app) won't work and errors out if I press a button.

I click run, and it builds, but when I click a button in the iOS simulator the app crashes and brings me back to Xcode with an error.
[image]

I don't know what I did wrong. It brings me to the main.m file when we didn't even deal with that in the Stanford guide (maybe it has to do with the fact that the Stanford guide uses iOS 5.0 and I'm on 5.1?).

Here's the project if anyone wants to take a lot at it. I'm just really confused.

http://cl.ly/212A3q3J1m1F1y3A041A

(Also, did I just need to include the xcodeproject file, or was I right in including the whole project folder in a zip file?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have your buttons linked to a selector called digitedPressed:

They also appear to correctly be linked to digitPressed.  Just remove the references to digitedPressed.  (Right click the Calculator View Controller in your storyboard)

Don't forget to check the XCode debugger!  This is the error the XCode debugger showed me:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CalculatorViewController digitedPressed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9129cc0'
```

Comment: Thanks greatly, that's exactly it. Now that I think about if I remember linking it to another one accidentally, and I evidently didn't remove it properly. Cheers for the help, that means a lot. :)

Comment: Had the same issue and found that the buttons were somehow linked twice in xcode. Removed the extra reference and they work great. Thanks for the fix @benuuu